# How to call sql server function from java(netbeans)

Tags: java, sql-server, function, call

at first, sorry for my english is so bad

i've stuck to call my function on sql server in java.

this is my code in sqlserver :

```
   GO
   IF OBJECT_ID (N'GET_DATE', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
      DROP FUNCTION GET_DATE;

   GO
   CREATE FUNCTION GET_DATE()
      RETURNS CHAR(12)
   AS
   BEGIN

   DECLARE @NO_ORDER CHAR(12), @NO_ORDER_MAKS INT


   declare @noSPK char(16),@noSPKmaks int;
   if (exists(select * from orders_spp))
        begin
            SELECT @NO_ORDER_MAKS = MAX(CONVERT(INT,(SUBSTRING(NO_ORDER,7,4)))) from 
   ORDERS_SPP;

            SET @NO_ORDER = CONVERT(CHAR(2),
   (right(datepart(year,getdate()),2))) +
            '-' + 
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(month(getdate()) as varchar(2)),2) +
            '-' +
            REPLICATE('0',4-LEN(CONVERT(varchar(30),@NO_ORDER_MAKS)))+
            CONVERT(varchar(30),@NO_ORDER_MAKS+1) +
            '/' +
            'P';
        end   ;                            
  else
        set @NO_ORDER = CONVERT(CHAR(2),(right(datepart(year,getdate()),2))) +
            '-' + 
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(month(getdate()) as varchar(2)),2) +
            '-' +
            '0001/P';




       RETURN @NO_ORDER;
       END;

       GO
       SELECT dbo.GET_DATE() AS 'RESULT'
```

what should i type the command for call the function in java ?
please help me, 
thanks :)

Comment: You can't do that with a *command*. You'll have to write a program.

Comment: Use [JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) and define input/output params. [Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/callablestatement.html) are some examples.